# regex should accept only 5 only 7 alphabet

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

I have this regex

```
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[gmail | yahoo | hotmail]{5,7}.[com | net | org]{3}$/
```

I want to accept just "gmail hotmail and yahoo" with ".com .net and .org"
Is there any method...to set the above regex according to my needs.

Also how to set the range so that it only accept the length of 5 and 7 characters.

Comment: `(gmail|yahoo|hotmail)` but... why? And if you're specifying strings to match, you don't want any quantifier on that (unless you're looking to match `"gmailgmailgmailgmailgmail"`

Comment: Use an alternation with a `|` instead of using that in the character class  `^[\w.]+@(?:gmail|yahoo|hotmail)\.(?:com|net|org)$`

Comment: Using a regular expression to check a mail address is useless, unless you're using the [complete expression](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). Your example would allow `johndoe@gmail.com` but not `johndoe+alias@gmail.com` although they both end in the same mailbox.

Comment: @The fourth bird thanks men it work for me

Comment: what do you mean by `length of 5 and 7 characters`?

Comment: @Andreas also, if it allows for the domain name and the TLD *separately*, you could put in `gmail.net`

Comment: how do i validate that email must start with alphabet...not with number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for this looks like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+@(gmail|yahoo|hotmail)\.(com|net|org)$
```

#### Explanation

Squared brackets (`[]`) are used to test for testing a character in a group of given characters. Round brackets (`()`) are used to test for a particular string (not character) in a group of given strings. You should read the `|` as "or".

**Examples**

- `[abc]` will match `a` or `b` or `c`.
- `(A1|B2|C2)` will match `A1`, `B2` or `C3`.

Additionally, the `.` character will be interpreted as "any character" if you don't escape it (`\.`), except when being using inside squared brackets.

Comment: That;s a correct *syntax* but I'm not sure that's a correct regex. Leaving aside the validity of the name, this allows `gmail.net` which is not a correct email domain.

Comment: As a separate note "*Additionally, the `.` character will be interpreted as "any character" if you don't escape it (`\.`).*" this is not true if it's inside character class. `[.]` will never be interpreted as anything but a literal `.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions

Comment: @VLAZ The regex is doing what OP asked for, so I consider it correct. Might be a case of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Thanks for your information regarding the `.`, I added that information to the answer.

Comment: how do i validate that email must start with alphabet...not with number.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Just put in another block in the beginning like this: `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._]+...`.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan If my answer solved your problem, you can accept it as answer by clicking the big checkbox next to the answer.

Comment: it help me but i don't know where it is to select the best answer... thanks

Comment: @MuhammadHassan You can find an explanation [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) :)